# Здравствуйте, помогите правильно настроить .htaccess файл для ЧПУ

Tags: php, .htaccess

помогите правильно настроить .htaccess файл для ЧПУ. 
Нужно это 
http://shop.loc/news.php?category=1&url=last
перевести на 
http://shop.loc/news/1/last.
Пробовал так: `RewriteRule ^news([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /news.php?category=$1&url=$2 [L]`. Но не реагирует. В чем ошибка.

RewriteRule работает для индекс файла. Доступ открыт.

```
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Опишите вопрос детально, какая структура проекта у Вас есть и что Вы конкретно хотите сделать (если используете фреймворк, то какой), также укажите каким локальным сервером пользуетесь

Comment: Нужно это http://shop.loc/news.php?category=1&url=last перевести на это http://shop.loc/news/1/last при переходе. Фреймворк не использую. Что писать в .htaccess файле используя модуль mod_rewrite